# How to dynamically change resource of BackgroundColor?

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light, dynamicresource

I have following control. I want to change background color on some event trigger. I want to make this `clrGray` resource as color on some event click.

I have tried by following way but it didn't work :(

XAM:

```
<local:RoundedFrame x:Name="MyFrame1" HeightRequest="16" IsVisible="True" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource clrGreen}">
```

CS:

```
//On Some event
    //Not working
    MyFrame1.SetDynamicResource(MyFrame1.BackgroundColor, "clrGreen");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate some more on your problem? Do you wish to simply change the background color of your frame on changing the value of "clrGreen" key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Xamarin.Forms dynamic resources. Below is a link to the Xamarin documentation:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/dynamic/

They are very easy to use/implement, and do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the color dynamically like this: `App.Current.Resources["yourColorKey"] = Color.FromHex("hexColor");`

Example:

Your App.xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <!--  Application resource dictionary  -->

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="backgroundColor">#0066B3</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

Your xaml file:

```
<StackLayout>

    <StackLayout
        Margin="10"
        BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource backgroundColor}"
        HeightRequest="30"
        WidthRequest="30" />

     <Button x:Name="btnColorChange" Text="Click me!" />

</StackLayout>
```

In your event handler:

```
 private void OnBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     App.Current.Resources["backgroundColor"] = Color.FromHex("#F15A29");
 }
```